# Android Samsung ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE does not save to correct filename

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-camera

After many hours of debuging, I am not able to save a picture Intent on a Samsung Android phone into the correct file. Here following code (Kotlin):

```
 val filename=File(getExternalStorageDirectory()?.toString()+"/test.jpg")
 if (filename != null) {
   val takePictureIntent=Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
   takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filename)
   startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
   }
```

It will save it always in the folder of the sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20181104_181922.jpg (i.e. the date and time) insted of filename.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Also the return value of onActivityResult does not show the filename but only "null". See following code: What did I wrong?

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent?) {
    ...
    val returnedFilename = data?.getData()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea why?

`EXTRA_OUTPUT` is a hint, not a command. Ideally, all camera apps would honor it as part of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` processing. There is no requirement that they do so, and many camera apps have `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations that do not.

> Also the return value of onActivityResult does not show the filename but only "null"

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a `Uri` through `onActivityResult()`. So, it is supposed to be `null`.

Comment: That's what I feared. Therefore the simplest will be looking for the newest file and then rename it.  ...

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger: You don't necessarily know where the file is. You may not even have access to it. Only use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` in cases where you are willing to ask the user to help you find the photo (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`), or are willing to just `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`, when the camera app fails to put the image in the proper spot.

Comment: You are absolutly right. As you say, it is even worse. At the end I'll write my own camera app. I wanted to avoid this, but that's what is left....